# Changes to IIS 6 Configuration Lost After Service Restart

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6

IIS 6 running on Windows 2003 with SP2.  When I make any changes to IIS's configuration (add a site, change an existing site's settings, etc.) and then restart IIS, all my changes are lost.  Uninstalling and re-installing IIS doesn't fix it (yes, I used the SP2 installation disk).  Google turns up nothing.

What could be going on?  How can I fix this or figure out how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using `iisreset` to restart IIS.  According to [this Knowledge Base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286196), the `iisreset` command will force the shutdown of the IIS Admin Service, which can cause any pending metabase changes to be lost.

The solution is to use the net stop and net start commands to stop and start all the IIS services.